# Xamarin -Error al restaurar el paquete. Revirtiendo los cambios del paquete para App.Android'. 0

Tags: android, c#, xamarin, nuget

estoy tratando de instalar un paquete para mi proyecto en **Xamarin** desde **NuGet** , alguien sabe a que se deba este error que me aparece en consola?

> Error al restaurar el paquete. Revirtiendo los cambios del paquete para 'OwServiceX.Android'.         0

Comment: ¿Has ejecutado Visual Studio como administrador?

Comment: amigo cómo pudiste solucionar este error?, ando batallando por esto

Comment: @JorgeGonzalez borré el caché Nuget y borre todos los bin y obj